# Пошли или пойдём?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Часто в разговоре ловлю себя и других на слове "пошли", например в собственном выражении: "пошли, чего остановился...". Может в данном контексте правильнее сказать "пойдём"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Использование форм прошедшего времени в качестве повелительного наклонения вполне нормально.

Comment: Соглашусь, но мне кажется, что формы "пойдем", "пойдемте" более предпочтительны.

Comment: Это смотря где. 

Вы модетет себе представить, скажем, инструктора по парашютному спорту, который сказал бы перед прыжком "пойдем" вместо "пошли"? Я - нет.

Answer (score 8):

Из наблюдений о практике использования этих слов я бы ответил, что обе формы приемлемы, но "пошли" (ни в коем случае не "пошлите") предпочтительна в разговорной речи, в общении с близкими по социальной группе лицами, а "пойдем(те)" чаще используется в общеупотребительном значении, причем как в книжной, так и в разговорной речи. Я бы сказал, что это более вежливая, тяготеющая к литературной норме форма призыва, повеления.

Comment: Насчет "пошлите" есть некоторые сомнения. 
Вы о каком значении вообще?

Comment: Естественно, не о пошлости

Comment: Тогда я Вас не понимаю.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду то, что слово "пошли" тоже имеет значение "говори пошлости"?

Comment: Это-то я понимаю. А вот то, что написано про "ни в коем случае не" - не понимаю ни разу. "Пошлите его по известному адресу" - это что? не нормативно? ;)

Comment: >Пошлите его по известному адресу"

@behemothus, из контекста понятно, что @виктор1799 имеет в виду форму прошедшего времени от глагола "пойти", а не повелительное наклонение от глагола "послать" как в вашем примере. Фраза: *Пошлите вместе со мной* - действительно неприемлема.

Comment: @behemothus, в вопросе рассматриваются слова "пошли" и "пойдём". Оба слова в начальной форме - "пойти". Считать что кто-то тут будет говорить про омонимичные словоформы от "послать" или "пошлить", по-моему, довольно нелепо.

> А в прошедшем времени формы "-те" не существует.

Именно это и написано у Виктора.

Comment: Именно это и написано у Виктора.

Не вижу. Вижу, что вам опять потроллить некого.

Comment: >от "послать" или "пошлить", по-моему, довольно нелепо.

Однако: "Именно это и написано у Виктора".

>Пошлите вместе со мной - действительно неприемлема.

А как же вежливая форма?

behemothus,

Марк Из видимо имеет в виду, что Виктор имел в виду в оcновном ответе. Нельзя "пошлите" в значении "пойдёмте". Как повелительное наклонение первого лица.

Comment: Вопрос всплыл... Поставлю точку в этом разговоре. Виктор своей оговоркой в скобках запутал тогда основательно. Использование формы вежливости "-те" при глаголе в форме прошедшего времени настолько дико, что я не мог взять в тол, что Виктор имеет в виду именно это. Сейчас вот - дошло. Спасибо и извините. Остальное - ну в общем-то вопрос закрыт, спорить особо не о чем.

Answer (score 1):

Из песни: Он сказал "Поехали!" и махнул рукой. Это гагаринское "поехали" на английский переводят как let's go. Вы можете представить себе, чтобы Гагарин сказал "Поедем!", как будто он не совсем уверен, примут его предложение или нет?
В русском языке и прошедшее и настоящее и будущее время может использоваться в качестве повелительной формы. Например, "поехали", "едем", "поедем" - все три формы могут использоваться в качестве повелительной формы. 
Как мне кажется, формы в прошедшем и настоящем времени более что ли повелительные.

Answer (score 0):

Соглашусь, "пошли" сподвигает собеседника вместе с вами в настоящем времени пошлить (от инф. "пошлить"). На мой взгляд, в повелительном наклонении употребление "пошли" не красиво и, если и является индикатором родства и близости какой-либо социальной группы, то самой низшей. Глагол "пошли" имеет все признаки глагола прошедшего времени и может употребляться только в отношение 3 лица множественного числа, а так же, являясь глаголом совершенного вида, иначе говоря "произошедшим", а не побудительным показателем плохой учёбы в школе.
"Они пошли в школу", но "Пойдём в школу!, или "Мы пойдём в школу".

Comment: Какая ерунда...

Comment: **Все** говорят и "пошли" и "пойдем(те)" в качестве побудительной форму от идти. Кроме может очень небольшего количества чудаков, которые любят расставлять людей на высшие и низшие социальные группы, и которые очень озабочены к какой группе их отнесут. И не только прошедшее от "идти" используется в качестве побудительной формы, но и от кучи других глаголов. Это совершенно нормально для русского языка.

Comment: Повелительное, и вроде бы уважительное от «пошли», в смысле «пойдём», — «пошлите» не то слово «не красиво», но и смешно, как обернувшееся просьбой, т. к. на слух легко предположить, что образовано от «послать». А вот просьба отправить письмо с этим словом будет вполне нормальна.

Answer (score 0):

Булат Шалвович, А.Толстой, Н. Гумилев, и многие другие, именно в литературе, в смысле "пойдём"  использовали слово "пошли! Т.О, слово "пошли"( со мной, куда-либо) стало вполне литературным! Хотя с точки зрения логики пойдём все же правильнее употреблять, т.к. пошли от шли. т.е прошедшее время, а пойдём от слова идём, настоящее время.
" раз пошли на дело, выпить захотелось" по другому не скажешь, а вот " бери шинель, пошли домой" можно! Но слов из песни не выкинешь....

Answer (score 0):

С моей точки зрения "пошли" может быть использовано в двух случаях:

1. В повелительном наклонении образованном от глагола послать — "Пошли его туда-то за тем-то";
2. В изъявительном наклонении прошедшего времени множественного числа — "Они пошли туда-то".

"Пошлите" может быть использовано аналогично первому варианту:

1. "Пошлите его туда-то за тем-то",

а так же:

2. От слова "Пошлить": "Вы, сударь, пошлите и, даже, не краснеете".

Для предложения пойти куда-то, составить компанию и т.д. надо использовать "Пойдем" или вежливую форму "Пойдемте".